# Android is not calling onKeyUp when multiple keys pressed

Tags: java, android, keyboard-events

I'm programming a small game in `Java` for `Android`, and I'm having trouble handling input. For early testing, I'm using hardware keyboard input, but I intend to use gamepad controls eventually.

The issue I am having is this: when the user holds one `key` for more than about 10 seconds, and in the meantime presses and releases a number of other keys, the `onKeyUp()` function for that first key is not called when it is eventually released.

I have not found a completely minimal repro, but I can trigger this reliably on two different `emulators` and a physical Nexus 5 (with a gamepad that presents itself as a keyboard).

The relevant code, with redundancies and log statements removed:

```
public class GameSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public final static short VBTN_FORWARD      = 0;
    public final static short VBTN_BACKWARD     = 1;
    // snipped several more similar constants
        public AtomicIntegerArray virtual_button_state = new AtomicIntegerArray(7);

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        if (event.isLongPress() || event.getRepeatCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_W:
                virtual_button_state.incrementAndGet(GameRenderer.VBTN_FORWARD);
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S:
                virtual_button_state.incrementAndGet(GameRenderer.VBTN_BACKWARD);
                return true;
            // snipped several more similar cases
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_W:
                virtual_button_state.decrementAndGet(GameRenderer.VBTN_FORWARD);
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S:
                virtual_button_state.decrementAndGet(GameRenderer.VBTN_BACKWARD);
                return true;
            // snipped several more similar cases
        }
    }
}
```

I have done extensive testing, and trace statements show that the onKeyUp() is not being called **at** **all**. Whatever the problem is, it is preventing the event from reaching my GLSurfaceView in the first place.

Possibly-relevant other information:

- My activity is fullscreen with no title
- My renderer is running in RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY
- My renderer is not yet well-optimized and frequently skips frames
- I am processing touch events at the same time
- This problem manifests regularly in normal gameplay. If this cannot be solved, the project is dead.

Comment: Could you be specific about where these methods are defined?  In an activity or a view?  What API levels have you tried?

Comment: @DougStevenson Those methods are defined in my view - the only view in the app, at the moment, and it does not seem to be losing focus.

I am using API level 22. I have not experimented with other levels - do you think that might hold the solution?

Comment: I don't really know, maybe there are different behaviors that have been fixed in different API levels.

Comment: @DougStevenson The problem persists under API levels 21 and 23. I will test other levels down to 18 once they download. Lower levels cannot be tested because I am already relying on OpenGL ES 3.0 features.

Comment: @DougStevenson The problem persists down to API level 18. I did some testing to find related factors, though, and found that commenting out my onTouchEvent handler makes it significantly harder (but not impossible) to trigger the problem, and that in some cases it is not the held-down key that has the keyUp event skipped. Is this perhaps a bug in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved - error was not quite as I originally described. There was a subtle bug in the test code I had written to detect if focus was being lost, which lead me to incorrect conclusions about the cause of the problem.

Focus was in fact being lost, during touch events, and sometimes was not regained by the time the keyUp event fired. Multiple simultaneous key events made this more likely, which is why that was mistakenly included in the repro, and why I mistakenly focused on multiple keypresses instead of simultaneous touch events.

Ultimate cause of the issue was a failure to call setFocusableInTouchMode(true) in my view constructor.